# Why won't this print small costs of items that do not requires sales tax?

Tags: python

If you were to enter 1 for "What is the price of the item?" and 1 for "What is the quantity desired?" and no for "Is this item taxable?" it will not print any results. Now, with larger numbers, such as 10 for "price" and 5 for "quantity" and no for "taxable", it will print. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
costOfItem = int(input('What is the price of the item? '))
quantityOfItem = int(input('What is the quantity desired? '))
sales_tax = input('Is this item taxable? ')


if costOfItem <= 25 and sales_tax == 'yes':
    shipping = 6
    subTotal = costOfItem * quantityOfItem
    salesTax = subTotal * 0.07
    totalCost = shipping + subTotal + salesTax
    print('Subtotal is $', format(subTotal, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('Sales tax is $', format(salesTax, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('Shipping is $', format(shipping, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('Total cost is $', format(totalCost, ',.2f'), sep='')

elif costOfItem >= 25 and sales_tax == 'no':
    shipping = 0
    subTotal = costOfItem * quantityOfItem
    salesTax = 0
    totalCost = shipping + subTotal + salesTax
    print('Subtotal is $', format(subTotal, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('Sales tax is $', format(salesTax, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('Shipping is $', format(shipping, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('Total cost is $', format(totalCost, ',.2f'), sep='')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your conditions:

```
if costOfItem <= 25 and sales_tax == 'yes':
...
elif costOfItem >= 25 and sales_tax == 'no':
```

You very specifically handle *only* two cases: small taxable sales, and large non-taxable sales.  You ignore the other two cases.

You have to re-work your logic.  Most of your computation and output is identical in the two cases.  You need one `if` to check order size and set `shipping`, the other to check whether to apply tax (and compute it).

Comment: I figured it out and I used the two if statements like you mentioned. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't print because, you only allow it to print if the number is under 25 when `sales_tax` is `yes`, and also for numbers bigger than 25, if there `sales_tax` is not `no` it won't print, to make it always print, you have to remove the second part of the `and` from both `if` statements, like:

```
costOfItem = int(input('What is the price of the item? '))
quantityOfItem = int(input('What is the quantity desired? '))
sales_tax = input('Is this item taxable? ')


if costOfItem <= 25:
    shipping = 6
    subTotal = costOfItem * quantityOfItem
    salesTax = subTotal * 0.07
    totalCost = shipping + subTotal + salesTax
    print('Subtotal is $', format(subTotal, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('Sales tax is $', format(salesTax, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('Shipping is $', format(shipping, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('Total cost is $', format(totalCost, ',.2f'), sep='')

elif costOfItem >= 25:
    shipping = 0
    subTotal = costOfItem * quantityOfItem
    salesTax = 0
    totalCost = shipping + subTotal + salesTax
    print('Subtotal is $', format(subTotal, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('Sales tax is $', format(salesTax, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('Shipping is $', format(shipping, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('Total cost is $', format(totalCost, ',.2f'), sep='')
```

You're currently not fitting all the conditions that could happen.

Comment: I completely understand what you're saying, but I still have to make the ```salesTax``` equal 7% if the user inputs 'yes' for ```sales_tax```. And, I have to make the ```salesTax``` equal zero if the user inputs 'no' for ```sales_tax```. This is what I'm stuck on...

Comment: @j_chicago Can you edit you question with the examples

Comment: I have figured it out by using two if statments. Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: I just joined this website, so I am still figuring out the dynamics. Thanks.

Comment: @U10-Forward: Accepting your answer would be incorrect, I think, as it probably does *not* solve the underlying problem.  It ignores the sales tax input, and makes a superfluous and overlapping test of `costOfItem`.